# Using cms_shiny in a django project error "cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils'..."

Tags: python, r, django, django-cms

I am trying to create a web app using django and I would like part of it to show a shiny dashboard. Recently I have been trying to use djangocms-shiny-app 0.1.3 package to accomplish this; however, after following the setup guide for the package, I am running into an error

```
File "C:\Users\rdkbh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cms_shiny\models.py", line 2, in <module>
   from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField
 File "C:\Users\rdkbh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\filer\fields\image.py", line 4, in <module>
   from .. import settings
 File "C:\Users\rdkbh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\filer\settings.py", line 11, in <module>
   from .utils.loader import load_object
 File "C:\Users\rdkbh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\filer\utils\loader.py", line 13, in <module>
   from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\rdkbh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

If anyone knows what is causing the error (Based on the error message I believe it is something to do with cms_shiny) and how to fix it or if there are any better packages for integrating a shiny app into Django I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This page has a good step by step tutorial for displaying a shiny app from a Django project. https://pawamoy.github.io/posts/django-auth-server-for-shiny/#overview

Comment: Looks like you're using a new version of django which doesn't have six. Six was for python compatibility when you weren't sure if users would have python 2 or 3 so it may still exist in projects, but not all. You should look for a newer version of `filer` that works with your django version. Alternatively look into `pip-tools` as it should help ensure compatibility between all your requirements.